# Why is python skipping a line?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm pretty new to Python (just started teaching myself a week ago), so my debugging skills are weak right now. I tried to make a program that would ask a user-submitted number of randomly-generated multiplication questions, with factors between 0 and 12, like a multiplication table test.

```
import math
import random

#establish a number of questions
questions = int(input("\n How many questions do you want?     "))     

#introduce score
score = 1

for question in range(questions):
    x = random.randrange(0,13)
    y = random.randrange(0,13)

    #make the numbers strings, so they can be printed with strings
    abc = str(x)
    cba = str(y)
    print("What is " + abc + "*" + cba +"?")

    z = int(input("Answer here:   "))
    print z
    a = x*y

    #make the answer a string, so it can be printed if you get one wrong
    answer = str(a)

    if z > a or z < a:
        print ("wrong, the answer is " + answer)
        print("\n")

        #this is the line that's being skipped
        score = score - 1/questions
    else:
        print "Correct!"
        print ("\n")

finalscore = score*100
finalestscore = str(finalscore)
print (finalestscore + "%")
```

The idea was that every time the user gets a question wrong, score (set to 1) goes down by 1/question,so when multiplied by 100 it gives a percentage of questions wrong.  However, no matter the number of questions or the number gotten wrong, score remains 1, so finalestscore remains 100.  Line 26 used to be:
    if math.abs(z)-math.abs(a) != 0:
but 2.7.3 apparently doesn't acknowledge that math has an abs function.

Such a simple accumulator pattern doesn't seem like it would be an issue, even for an older version of Python.  Help?

Answer (score 5):

Try `score = score - 1.0/questions`

The problem is that you're doing integer division, which truncates to the nearest integer, so `1/questions` will always give 0.

Comment: Knew I was missing something!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using integers for all of your calculations. In particular, when you calculate `1/questions`, it truncates (rounds down) to an integer because both values in the calculation are integers.

To avoid this, you could instead use `1.0/questions` to make the calculations use floating point numbers instead (and not truncate)